# Force type to be integer and not float in python

Tags: python-2.x

I am writing a simple program that will calculate the sum of the digits. So for example `123` would be `1 + 2 + 3 = 6` simple. When I write my code

```
def sumOfNumber(number):
    sum = 0

    while(number >= 1):
        temp = number % 10
        sum += temp
        number /= 10

    return sum

main():
    sumOfNumber(123)
    # 6.53
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This code works in Python2, you are most likely using Python3 where the behaviour of /= is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using *Python3* where division `/` outputs floats. Replace the inplace division `/=` with integer division `//=` to get rid of decimals.

```
number //= 10
```

Although, if you want to manipulate a number digit by digit, it is better to cast it to a `str`. This allows to loop over its digits and sum them.

```
def sumOfNumber(number):
    digits = str(number)
    sum_ = 0

    for d in digits:
        sum_ += int(d)

    return sum_

sumOfNumber(123) # 6
```

Using the builtin `sum` function, you can even rewrite this function in a single line.

```
def sumOfNumber(number):
    return sum(int(x) for x in str(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just casting it, but if someone has a better solution please post as well.

```
def sumOfNumber(number): 
sum = 0
    while(number >= 1):
        temp = int(number % 10)
        sum += temp
        number = int(number / 10)

    return sum

main():
    sumOfNumber(123)
    # 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a =  input ("enter the numeraotr  ")
       a= int(a)
b = input ("enter the denomirator ")
       b= int(b)
if a%b == 0:
print(a/b)
else:
print(int(a/b),"And the remainder is=",a%b)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?